# Prevent USB flash drive from being used

Tags: linux, security, usb, driver

What I need, is to write a *linux program/driver* which will allow to use only flash drives with registered UUIDs.
Unregistered flash drives should not be accessible.

As I understand, if I have root access I can circumvent any kind of system like this. That is why I think it should work for non-priveledged users.

I really don't know where to start. Can this be done from user space? What would be limitations of this system?

Writing udev rule instead of program is not an answer, because this is my course project =)

**I do not have an option to recompile kernel or existing module**

Comment: You can do this with udev rules and a program that check for UUID in a database. Why you can't use udev rules?

Comment: If you don't want to go an easy way (udev), you can implement such blacklist directly in Kernel (namely USB drivers) and come up with some clever way to update the given list without recompiling Kernel. Any userspace solution would be redundant to udev imho.

Comment: I do not have option to recompile kernel or modules, because this russian military linux =)
Can this be done through some kind of proxy driver, which will be used instead of normal driver and forward functionality, when access is allowed, without copy-pasting flash driver code? Does flash drives use one unified driver?